# LiveReload Ionic: ​The connection to the server was unsuccessful (http://192.168.56.1:8100/)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, livereload

I'm trying to run my App at Android device with LiveReload. With "ionic run android" command, everything works but when I try to execute "ionic run android -l" to use livereload I'm getting this error after SplashScreen:

​The connection to the server was unsuccessful (http://192.168.56.1:8100/)

1. I'm using windows and I've created an inbound rule to allow 8100 and 35729 ports at Windows Firewall but still not working.
2. The Cordova Whitelist Plugin is also installed and configured at config.xml:

   `<content src="index.html"/>
   <access origin="*"/>
   <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*"/>
   <allow-navigation href="*"/>
   <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.56.1:8100"/>
   <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
   <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>`
3. I'm running to device using USB Cable.
4. Versions:

   - node v6.9.5   npm v4.3.0  ionic v2.2.1
5. I've already tried to add

   `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />​`

but in this case, I'm getting timeout error.
Could you help me?

Comment: are you under the same Wi-Fi?

Comment: @mosca90 thank you! My PC has two ethernet drivers and the app was starting with the wrong IP, I solve use "--adress <correct IP>

Comment: Good :D easier than expected!

Answer (score 1):

My PC has two ethernet drivers and the app was starting with the wrong IP, I solve using "--address

Comment: +1 | Had the same problem. I've tried to set the static LAN IP address on Ubuntu but switched to DHCP again. However, somehow the system was seeing two different IP addresses. Removing custom static IP solved my problem.

Comment: This response could be a little more clear. Using --address... where, how, why?!?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off windows firewall temporarily if you are on a PC. That might do the trick.

Comment: My PC has two ethernet drivers and the app was starting with the wrong IP, I solve using "--address <correct IP>